# Javascript Tab Navigation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs

```
  $(".wojo.tab.content").hide();
  $(".wojo.tabs a:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".wojo.tab.content:first").show();
  $(".wojo.tabs a").on('click', function () {
      $(".wojo.tabs a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".wojo.tab.content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).data("tab");
      $(activeTab).show();
```

I'm trying to make an href link direct to a specific tab.  I have two of them. Lets say 1 is "uprofile" and the other is "umember".  So I would like to be able to just: www.mysite.com/page/dashboard#profile or www.mysite.com/page/dashboard#umember

thanks ahead of time

Comment: Try and put up a demo it'll help you get a faster answer http://plnkr.co

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change the tab based of the hash?

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length>1) {
    var elem = $(hash);
    //do what you want to show it
}
```